# When (if ever) to modify checkpointed metadata of streaming query in case of failure?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have a doubt regarding Spark Checkpoints. I have spark streaming application and I'am managing Checkpoint n HDFS using following approach :-

```
 val checkpointDirectory = "hdfs://192.168.0.1:8020/markingChecksPoints"
  df.writeStream
        .foreachBatch { (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>
          batchDF
            .write
            .cassandraFormat(
              "table",
              "keyspace",
              "clustername"
            )
            .mode(SaveMode.Append)
            .save()
        }
        .outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
        .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointDirectory)
    }
```

Now When I run the Application, in checkpoint directory I got 4 folders:

- `commits`
- `offsets`
- `metadata`
- `sources`

In offsets folder- I have files for each offset consumed which is like this

```
v1
{"batchWatermarkMs":0,"batchTimestampMs":1574680172097,"conf":{"spark.sql.streaming.stateStore.providerClass":"org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider","spark.sql.streaming.flatMapGroupsWithState.stateFormatVersion":"2","spark.sql.streaming.multipleWatermarkPolicy":"min","spark.sql.streaming.aggregation.stateFormatVersion":"2","spark.sql.shuffle.partitions":"30"}}
{"datatopicname":{"23":441210,"8":3094007,"17":44862,"26":0,"11":4302147,"29":0,"2":3758094,"20":6273,"5":4620156,"14":15375428,"4":4511998,"13":10652363,"22":1247616,"7":1787900,"16":1239584,"25":0,"10":3441724,"1":1808759,"28":0,"19":4123,"27":0,"9":3293762,"18":68,"12":4439364,"3":5910468,"21":182,"15":13510271,"6":2510314,"24":0,"0":40337}}
```

So, now my query is in case of failure or any other scenario How can I modify my directory so that when Application is restarted it should take from that particular point?

I understand that whenever we restart the application , it will automatically pick from the checkpoint that is fine but just in case I want to start it from any Specific value or change. Then what should I do ?

- Shall I simply edit this "offsets" last created file.
- Delete the checkpoint directory and restart the application with custom checkpoint for first run so that new checkpoint directory will be created from that onward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be more files in the `checkpointLocation` directory (like `state` for stateful operators), but their role is exactly what you're asking for - in case of failure the stream processing engine of Spark Structured Streaming is going to resume a streaming query based on the checkpointed metadata.

Since these files are internal it's not recommended to amend the files in any way.

You can though (and perhaps that's one of the reasons why they're human-readable). Whether you change the existing offsets files or you create them from scratch does not really matter. The engine sees no difference. If the files are in proper format, they're going to be used. Otherwise, the checkpoint location will be of no use.

I'd rather use data source-specific options, e.g. `startingOffsets` for `kafka` data source to (re)start from specific offset.

Comment: Hi @Jacek - yes you are totally right. I just thought to discuss in case I can get any other approach to edit my checkpoint directory or files. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Hey @Jacek, I have a question. Will specifying startingOffsets in the query work when offsets are present for a Kafka topic in the checkpoint directory? As per the documentation (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#creating-a-kafka-source-for-batch-queries): "For streaming queries, this only applies when a new query is started, and that resuming will always pick up from where the query left off". My understanding is that if the checkpoint directory is present (and offsets have been written to it), the startingOffsets option will be ignored. Thanks.

Comment: @PrabhatikaVij That's my understanding too.